# How to pass parameter in stored procedure execution for OLE DB source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm having problems when executing a stored procedure in an OLE DB source in SSIS,

I have set the OLE DB source to SQL command and put the following:

[image]

This is the code for the SQL command text:

```
exec timesheet_r12..TIME_lynx_extract ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?

WITH RESULT SETS (
(
worker_reference    NVarchar(50),
placement_reference  NVarchar(10),
worker_name NVarchar(50),
job_title   NVarchar(100),
authorising_line_manager    NVarchar(100),
timesheet_date  datetime,
company_agent_name  NVarchar(100),
type_of_worker  NVarchar(100),
week_number NVarchar(100),
hours_worked    NVarchar(100),
rate_description    NVarchar(100),
rate_per_hour   NVarchar(10),
job NVarchar(100),
work_stage  NVarchar(100),
project_name    NVarchar(100),
location NVarchar(100)
)
)
```

The first 2 parameters that I need to send are @startweek and @endweek
for these,I need to find out how to send the last friday as "@endweek" and the friday of 4 weeks ago as "@startweek" (4 fridays before).

if I want to execute with hard coded @startweek and @endweek the Stored Procedure in the Database, I can do it with the following command:

```
exec timesheet_r12..TIME_lynx_extract
     '19 Jul 2018', 
     '16 Aug 2019',
     null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
```

this is the error I'm getting when executing the package in SSIS:

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\AGUIRRG2\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0207014 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [49]: The SQL command requires a parameter named "@startweek", which is not found in the parameter mapping.
Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0207014.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\AGUIRRG2\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[24756] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

So right now what I would need is to know how to pass the parameters to SSIS, and how to make them dynamic, `@startweek` and `@endweek` can be calculated.

Thank you.

Comment: Create 2 SSIS variables of date data type and set them using an expression, then supply these to the EXEC script. Since SSIS expressions aren't the best, I'd recommend creating a calendar table and a scalar funcion on your SQL Server and using it to find the last friday (the last friday 4 weeks ago is just substracting 4 weeks).

Comment: Also if you have to supply dates as varchar, make sure to use YYYY-MM-DD format and avoid language-specific names at all costs.

Comment: I have just tried to do it: https://i.imgur.com/uJX7ovB.png  I get the same error

Comment: it doesn't work by passing the parameter as my stored procedure would take it in sql server?  Also, I don't see the varchar as data type in SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue once working on a project.I think you need to do a specific mapping for your parameters

You can follow all steps mentioned in this article : [Mapping Stored Procedure Parameters in SSIS OLE DB Source Editor](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx)

Comment: I was able to make it work, yes, it was related to mapping